# auto m3u creation

Tags: android, m3u

I am looking for a solution to automatically create .m3u playlists for each music folder in my sdcard so that the music player can play music by folders. I had written a simple VB.Net app in the past that does exactly the above but apparently, it has to be run from Windows. Since I have no Java nor Android developing experience I found it quite hard to try to write a similar app that can be run directly from the phone. In a few words, the app does the following:

1) Searches the SD and lists all folders that contain 2 or more .mp3 files (just for user verification)
2) Creates in every listed folder above, a .m3u file that simply lists line-by-line all the mp3 files that exist in the specific folder.

Is there such an app or could someone spare some time and give me some rough instructions on how to create it in Eclipse 3.5.2 environment? (device used: Motorola Droid/Milestone, Android 2.1) I don't care about any graphics or complex UI, just a script to execute the above procedure that would give every "playlist-supporting" music player in Android, the precious ability to play music by folders. I know it is too much to ask but just in case!

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to launch this script on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

because I can download new songs and in general modify the existing collection from my phone where there is noneed to connect to a pc. also I may connect my phone to any pc and transfer new music folders and it may be the case where the remote pc doesnot have the vb runtime essentials on order to run my app, so running it from the phone offers far greater flexibility.